# Can't use Bose Soundlink mini with elementary OS

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I can't use my Bose Soundlink mini as a bluetooth speaker in elementary OS. I can pair the device, but it stays disconnected. Sometime it connects, but sound still go through the laptop speaker. In the sound panel my speaker doesn't appear.
Any idea ?

Thank you for your help!

Here are the results of the command `pactl list short | grep blue` :

```
7   module-bluetooth-policy     
8   module-bluetooth-discover       
9   module-bluez5-discover
```

Comment: I am not sure what the answer to your problem is, but I can at least confirm that this combination of OS and speaker works very well for me here. Perhaps the issue is more to do with the bluetooth driver on your PC than anything in eOS. I would check if you can select the speaker as the output device through the System Settings though, just in case as I have to do that sometimes.

Comment: I can't select my speaker as the output device. It doesn't appear, whereas it is recognized as an audio device (the icon is a speaker). Strange... How can I check if I need a new driver ?

Comment: Edit the question to add results for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues: [Bluetooth headphones not showing up as sound output on Dell XPS 15](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/bluetooth-headphones-not-showing-up-as-sound-output-on-dell-xps-15)

It seems to be fixed in the latest elementary OS Juno (based on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04).